# How can I replace and removing space in the keys in object javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have object like this :

```
let output = 
[
  {
    Email: 'haha@yopmail.com',
    KolomB: 'Haha',
    KolomC: 6,
    ' Kolom D ': '3.000.000',
    KolomE: 2022-01-01T16:59:48.000Z
  },
  {
    Email: 'blabla@gmail.com',
    KolomB: 'blabla',
    KolomC: 6,
    ' Kolom D ': '3.000.000',
    KolomE: 2022-01-01T16:59:48.000Z
  }
]
```

I want to remove the spaces if occurs in keys inside the object.

this is my desired output :

```
output = 
[
  {
    Email: 'haha@yopmail.com',
    KolomB: 'Haha',
    KolomC: 6,
    KolomD: '3.000.000',
    KolomE: 2022-01-01T16:59:48.000Z
  },
  {
    Email: 'blabla@gmail.com',
    KolomB: 'blabla',
    KolomC: 6,
    KolomD: '3.000.000',
    KolomE: 2022-01-01T16:59:48.000Z
  }
]
```

As you can see, i want to remove the space in `Kolom D` to be `KolomD` in `output` variable.

Here's what i've done before :

```
for (let i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
 Object.keys(output[i]).forEach(function(key) {
  key = key.replace(/\s+/g, "").replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "")
 })
}
```

but the `output` still not changing. How to push/changing the keys to the `output` ?

Please let me know if you need more information if it's still not enough to solve that problem

Comment: You can't modify keys. You can either create a new object or add a new property and remove the old one.

Comment: yea I would suggest adding a new property and removing the old one using `delete`

Comment: I was thinking making a new object with new keys. But, how can I insert the value from ```output``` to my new object with new keys ?

Comment: Why do you need two `replace`? I don't understand why the second `replace` is necessary.

Comment: yes, you right. that was my mistake using second replace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't modify keys. You can either create a new object or add a new property and remove the old one.

This is a way to create a new object

```js
let output = [{ Email: 'haha@yopmail.com', KolomB: 'Haha', KolomC: 6, ' Kolom D ': '3.000.000', KolomE: '2022-01-01T16:59:48.000Z' }, { Email: 'blabla@gmail.com', KolomB: 'blabla', KolomC: 6, ' Kolom D ': '3.000.000', KolomE: '2022-01-01T16:59:48.000Z' }];

output = output.map(el => 
  Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(el).map(([key, value]) => ([
    key.replace(/\s+/g, ""),
    value
  ])))
);

console.log(output);
```

The first `map` iterates over the array and converts each element. `Object.entries` converts each element to an array. The second `map` applies the algorithm from your question to each `key`. `Object.fromEntries` converts the array back to an object.

I also removed the second `.replace`. It's not necessary. The first `replace` already removes all spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```js
let output = 
[
  {
    Email: 'haha@yopmail.com',
    KolomB: 'Haha',
    KolomC: 6,
    ' Kolom D ': '3.000.000',
    KolomE: 2022-01-01T16:59:48.000Z
  },
  {
    Email: 'blabla@gmail.com',
    KolomB: 'blabla',
    KolomC: 6,
    ' Kolom D ': '3.000.000',
    KolomE: 2022-01-01T16:59:48.000Z
  }
]
for (let i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
 Object.keys(output[i]).forEach(function(key) {
  const newkey = key.replace(/\s+/g, "").replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "")
  const value = output[i][key];
  delete output[i][key];
  output[i][newkey] = value;
 })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for...of` loop and `String#replace`:

```js
const output = [ { Email: 'haha@yopmail.com', KolomB: 'Haha', KolomC: 6, ' Kolom D ': '3.000.000', KolomE: '2022-01-01T16:59:48.000Z' }, { Email: 'blabla@gmail.com', KolomB: 'blabla', KolomC: 6, ' Kolom D ': '3.000.000', KolomE: '2022-01-01T16:59:48.000Z' } ];

for(let [i, obj] of Object.entries(output)) {
    const newobj = Object.fromEntries(
        Object.entries(obj).map(([key,value]) => [key.replace(/\s+/g, ''),value])
    );
    output[+i] = newobj;
}

console.log( output );
```